# Tooltip Html for table google visualisation

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I would like to show a tooltip in HTML format on a  structure with the data of columns 2,3,4 which are hidden.

I can not get the addeventlistener to work when I'm doing an onmouseover on a cell.

I would like the tooltip to be triggered when moving the mouse over the column 'number' (col 1).

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div.google-visualization-tooltip {
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    background-color: red;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable,);

   // start chart
   function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    // add columns
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'number');
    data.addColumn('number', 'ok');
    data.addColumn('number', 'warnning');
    data.addColumn('number', 'nok');

    // add data
    data.addRows([
     ['Mike',18,10,3,5],
     ['Jim', 8,5,2,1],
     ['Alice', 12,6,3,3],
     ['Bob', 7,2,4,1],
     ['Sourav',9,1,0,8],
     ['Sunil', 16,15,0,1],
     ['Vinod', 19,14,4,1]
     ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0,1]); 

    table.draw(view, {allowHtml: true});

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'onmouseover', function(e){
     setTooltipContent(data,e.row);
    });
   }

   // set tooltip
   function setTooltipContent(data,row) {
    if (row != null) {
     var content = '<div class="custom-tooltip" ><table border="1"><tr><td>OK</td><td>warnnig</td><td>NOK</td></tr><tr><td>' + data.getValue(row, 2) + '</td><td>' + data.getValue(row, 3) + '</td><td>' + data.getValue(row, 4) + '</td></tr></table></div>'; //generate tooltip content

     var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("google-visualization-tooltip")[0];
      tooltip.innerHTML = content;
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id='table_div'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the table chart only publishes the following [events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#events)...

`'select', 'page', 'sort', 'ready'`

also, no container for `google-visualization-tooltip` exists for a table chart

to get the desired result, we can wait for the chart's `'ready'` event,
then listen for the `'mouseover` event on the table's container `<div>`.
as for `google-visualization-tooltip`, we can just add our own...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

// start chart
function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  // add columns
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'number');
  data.addColumn('number', 'ok');
  data.addColumn('number', 'warnning');
  data.addColumn('number', 'nok');

  // add data
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike',18,10,3,5],
    ['Jim', 8,5,2,1],
    ['Alice', 12,6,3,3],
    ['Bob', 7,2,4,1],
    ['Sourav',9,1,0,8],
    ['Sunil', 16,15,0,1],
    ['Vinod', 19,14,4,1]
    ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('table_div');
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,1]);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    container.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
      setTooltipContent(data, e);
    });
    container.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
      setTooltipContent(data, e);
    });
  });

  table.draw(view, {allowHtml: true});
}

// set tooltip
function setTooltipContent(data, e) {
  var col = null;
  var row = null;
  var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("google-visualization-tooltip")[0];

  if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
      col = (e.target.cellIndex);
      row = (e.target.parentNode.rowIndex - 1);
    }

    if ((row !== null) && (col === 1)) {
      var content = '<div class="custom-tooltip" ><table border="1"><tr><td>OK</td><td>warnnig</td><td>NOK</td></tr><tr><td>' + data.getValue(row, 2) + '</td><td>' + data.getValue(row, 3) + '</td><td>' + data.getValue(row, 4) + '</td></tr></table></div>'; //generate tooltip content
      tooltip.innerHTML = content;
      tooltip.style.display = 'block';
      tooltip.style.left = (e.pageX + 16) + "px";
      tooltip.style.top = (e.pageY + 16) + "px";
    } else {
      tooltip.style.display = 'none';
    }
  } else {
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
div.google-visualization-tooltip {
  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  width: auto;
  height:auto;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
<div class="google-visualization-tooltip"></div>
```

**notes**

**1)** the script library `jsapi` should no longer be used.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statements, see snippet above.

**2)** when adding event listeners to any google chart, such as `'ready'`, they should be assigned **before** drawing the chart...

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Now, if I want the tooltip to only show the cells in the 'number' column, how can I do? I guess I have to go through my painting with a loop?

In the final project, I have several columns and I want the tooltip to display the detail of the column that the mouse spends on it.